# Error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I am having some issues with my form_for, I keep getting this error

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

This is the form

```
           <%= form_for @blog do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_area :blogpost %>
            <%= f.submit  'Add Blog'%>
             <% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
 class BlogsController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @blogs = Blog.all  #.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
   end


 def create
  @blog = Blog.create(blog_params)
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Created a Blog" 
 end

 def update
  @blog = Blog.create(blog_params)
  redirect_to root_path 
 end

def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

 def new
 @blog = Blog.new
 end

 def edit
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
 end

def destroy
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @blog.destroy
 redirect_to root_path
end

private
 def blog_params
   params.require(:blog).permit(:blogpost)
 end

end
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your `form` belongs to which `view file`?

Comment: I have it in the index.html.erb that is in the blogs view folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it belongs to **`index.html.erb`**,you should be adding this line `@blog = Blog.new` to the `index` method.

```
def index
@blogs = Blog.all  
@blog = Blog.new
end
```

And also your **`update`** method is wrong.It should be like this to avoid getting error in the future.

```
def update
  @blog = Blog.update(blog_params)
  redirect_to root_path 
 end
```

Comment: It was that easy?? Thank you so much!